# ASUS 946gz7ma mainboard multimedia audio controller

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, drivers

Recently, I have installed Windows 7 ultimate, all drivers loaded up just fine, but I have issues with audio.  Multimedia Audio Controller shows up with yellow triangle under Device Manager.  Any suggestions where I can find Multimedia Audio Controller driver for ASUS 946gz7ma mother board for Windows 7 ultimate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that it's an asus motherboard? Because

https://www.google.ca/search?q=ASUS+946gz7ma&oq=ASUS+946gz7ma&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=ASUS+946gz7ma+motherboard

says otherwise...

If it's foxconn motherboard however, 
http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=Motherboard&U=en-us0000227

in tech support has some drivers that you should take a look at

Comment: I am pretty sure, but I will try those and let you know.  I think I might have tried one of those audio drivers, but not sure. Thanks!

Comment: @George So any updates on your issue?